# Javascript form.submit() doesn't work in Safari

Tags: javascript, html, forms, safari, form-submit

I have a simple function that create, append and submit a form from an HTML page, it works in all browser except Safari. I can't figure out why, any hint will be very welcome

here's my function:

```
function open(method, url, data, target) {
        var form = document.createElement("form");
        form.action = url;
        form.method = method;
        form.target = target;
        if (data) {
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                let input = document.createElement("textarea");
                input.name = i.toString();
                input.innerText = data[i];
                form.appendChild(input);
            }
        }
        form.style.display = "none";
        document.body.appendChild(form);
        form.submit();
        form.remove();
    }

    // use example
    var data = ["text1", "text2", "text3", "text4", "text5", "text6"];
    open("POST", "../result.php" , data, "_blank");
```

Ps: if it's possible I would avoid using JQuery

Comment: Are you using iframes? I remember safari having issues with iframes.

Comment: Does it work if you wait or don't do  the `form.remove();`

Comment: @ViRuSTriNiTy nope, no iframe

Comment: @mplungjan even without form.remove(); nothing happend

Comment: You can still Ajax without jQuery

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have set `target="_blank"` and are triggering the function during the script load (i.e. not from a user event like a click).

Since you are trying to open an automatic popup when the page loads, Safari is blocking you.

Don't use `_blank` or wait until something is clicked before calling your function.

Comment: Ok, If i don't use "_blank" it works but the result will load on the same page, what if i need to keep current page and open results on a new windows/tab?

Comment: Then wait for a button to be clicked. Popups are unpleasant at the best of times, on page load they are just awful, and browsers take steps to prevent authors from creating them.

Comment: Or use ajax or target an iframe (unless that is also frowned upon by safari)